# what type is this js encryption and how to decompile?

Tags: javascript

This is the code:

```
const _0x4c62db=_0x36a6;(function(_0x3b2af5,_0x3628c6){const _0x96767b=_0x36a6,_0x5cd5d7=_0x3b2af5();while(!![]){try{const _0x11879c=-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x1c3))/0x1*(parseInt(_0x96767b(0x1ba))/0x2)+-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x1df))/0x3+-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x239))/0x4*(-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x21b))/0x5)+-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x245))/0x6+-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x220))/0x7*(-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x22b))/0x8)+-parseInt(_0x96767b(0x1bf))/0x9*(parseInt(_0x96767b(0x1f1))/0xa)+parseInt(_0x96767b(0x22f))/0xb;if(_0x11879c===_0x3628c6)break;else _0x5cd5d7['push'](_0x5cd5d7['shift']());}catch(_0x485281){_0x5cd5d7['push'](_0x5cd5d7['shift']());}}}(_0x4fde,0xd0791));let NavigateTo='';window[_0x4c62db(0x1f3)]=renderLoading;function renderLoading(){const _0xe70cdd=_0x4c62db;Pace[_0xe70cdd(0x208)](),Pace['start'](),Pace[_0xe70cdd(0x22a)][_0xe70cdd(0x1de)]();}$(_0x4c62db(0x1d3))['datepicker']({'autoclose':!![]})[_0x4c62db(0x1db)](_0x4c62db(0x1c4),_0x4c62db(0x1f8));function _0x36a6(_0x3b4081,_0x35ea5d){const _0x4fde40=_0x4fde();return _0x36a6=function(_0x36a6ae,_0x4122d8){_0x36a6ae=_0x36a6ae-0x1b9;let _0x46d942=_0x4fde40[_0x36a6ae];return _0x46d942;},_0x36a6(_0x3b4081,_0x35ea5d);}function _0x4fde(){const _0x569c75=['&type=username','title','(max-width:\x20767px)','attr','<tr><td>','navbarCollapse','#refreshOverview','success','reverse','none','<h6>Item</h6>','#Charpage','4726465xtVRdR','post','login','display','serialize','273YYnCtB','\x22></i>\x20<a\x20href=\x22','input[name=\x22strPassword\x22]','</div>','#register','input[name=\x22strEmail\x22]','json','/api/register','Please\x20fill\x20username\x20input','reset','bar','61448THXNrw','ajax','reward','<i\x20class=\x22fa\x20fa-user\x22></i>\x20','17372850ZdPJfz','.storeinfo','input[name=\x22unm\x22]','toLowerCase','failed','Item','<i\x20class=\x22','loginAlert','#accountName','href','4gXEYtr','msg','Email','/api/char/overview','Username','#formLogin','location','focus','\x22\x20target=\x22_blank\x22>','fa\x20fa-sync-alt\x20fa-spin','body','Gold','1115964JMgjBC','fa\x20fa-sync-alt','#login','2246cERkXR','Collapse','#formChangePassword','<li\x20class=\x22nav-item\x20overview-box\x22><span\x20class=\x22float-left\x22>','click','5510205qCrWnH',':\x20</td><td><font\x20color=\x22green\x22>+','#sideName','status','11BOmmCY','setDate','</button>','entries','Icon','library/wiki/modal/store','<br/>','#changeemail','Message','Coins','</a><br/>','sMsg','Status','Name','scroll','Title','#DoB','#formRegister','error','Z3JvLmRscm93LXNh','formChangeEmail','info','scrollY','#accountEmail','datepicker','#formChangeEmail','account','render','3479115LGNbmn','.accountInfo','#logout',':\x20</span><span\x20class=\x22float-right\x22>\x20','class','POST','Upgrade','show','formChangePassword','style','#formChangeUsername','loginBox','.userOverview','/api/logout/now','<h6>Title</h6>-\x20','/profile/','Price','input[name=\x22strPassword2\x22]','10WMYeRn','indexOf','onbeforeunload','origin','val','JSON','split','-13y','user','#accountLogin','getElementById','\x20</span></li>','System\x20got\x20broken','input[name=\x22strGender\x22]','html','data','<div\x20class=\x22alert\x20alert-danger\x20alert-dismissible\x20fade\x20show\x22\x20role=\x22alert\x22>','preventDefault',')</font>','overview','System\x20got\x20broken!','#changeusername','<span\x20aria-hidden=\x22true\x22>&times;</span>','stop','matchMedia','<br/><br/>','formRegister','/api/char/update','Success\x20Login','/wiki/item/'];_0x4fde=function(){return _0x569c75;};return _0x4fde();}function loginAlert(){const _0x515bd1=_0x4c62db;NavigateTo=_0x515bd1(0x1dd);let _0x5ee19b=_0x515bd1(0x201);_0x5ee19b+='Please\x20<strong>Login</strong>\x20to\x20Access\x20Manage\x20Account!',_0x5ee19b+='<button\x20type=\x22button\x22\x20class=\x22close\x22\x20data-dismiss=\x22alert\x22\x20aria-label=\x22Close\x22>',_0x5ee19b+=_0x515bd1(0x207),_0x5ee19b+=_0x515bd1(0x1c5),_0x5ee19b+=_0x515bd1(0x223),document[_0x515bd1(0x1fb)](_0x515bd1(0x236))['innerHTML']=_0x5ee19b;}function retrieveUserData(){const _0x4012e3=_0x4c62db;$(_0x4012e3(0x215))[_0x4012e3(0x212)](_0x4012e3(0x1e3),_0x4012e3(0x242)),$[_0x4012e3(0x22c)]({'url':_0x4012e3(0x23c),'type':_0x4012e3(0x21c),'dataType':'json','success':function(_0x48dae1){const _0x5cfb98=_0x4012e3;$(_0x5cfb98(0x215))[_0x5cfb98(0x212)]('class',_0x5cfb98(0x246));let _0x4a2d49='';for(const [_0x24c7b0,_0x590981]of Object[_0x5cfb98(0x1c6)](_0x48dae1[_0x5cfb98(0x204)])){_0x4a2d49+=_0x5cfb98(0x1bd)+_0x24c7b0+_0x5cfb98(0x1e2)+_0x590981+'\x20</span></li>';}let _0x8af578='';for(const [_0x5d812c,_0x3ad346]of Object[_0x5cfb98(0x1c6)](_0x48dae1['user'])){_0x8af578+=_0x5cfb98(0x1bd)+_0x5d812c+':\x20</span><span\x20class=\x22float-right\x22>\x20'+_0x3ad346+_0x5cfb98(0x1fc);}$(_0x5cfb98(0x1eb))[_0x5cfb98(0x1ff)](_0x4a2d49),$(_0x5cfb98(0x1e0))[_0x5cfb98(0x1ff)](_0x8af578),$(_0x5cfb98(0x237))[_0x5cfb98(0x1f5)](_0x48dae1['user'][_0x5cfb98(0x23d)]),$(_0x5cfb98(0x1da))[_0x5cfb98(0x1f5)](_0x48dae1[_0x5cfb98(0x1f9)][_0x5cfb98(0x23b)]),$(_0x5cfb98(0x1c1))['html'](_0x5cfb98(0x22e)+_0x48dae1[_0x5cfb98(0x1f9)][_0x5cfb98(0x23d)]+'\x27s\x20Overview');},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();}});};try{window[_0x4c62db(0x23f)][_0x4c62db(0x1f4)][_0x4c62db(0x232)]()[_0x4c62db(0x1f2)](window['atob'](_0x4c62db(0x1d6))[_0x4c62db(0x1f7)]('')[_0x4c62db(0x217)]()['join'](''))===-0x1&&(document['body']['style']['display']=_0x4c62db(0x218),document[_0x4c62db(0x210)]='');}catch(_0x21850){document[_0x4c62db(0x243)][_0x4c62db(0x1e8)][_0x4c62db(0x21e)]='none',document[_0x4c62db(0x210)]='';}$(function(){const _0x1d15fb=_0x4c62db;$(document)['on'](_0x1d15fb(0x1be),_0x1d15fb(0x1fa),function(_0x46fc1d){const _0x84919e=_0x1d15fb;_0x46fc1d[_0x84919e(0x202)](),loginAlert(),document['getElementsByName'](_0x84919e(0x1f9))[0x0][_0x84919e(0x240)]();const _0x1ed13f=document[_0x84919e(0x1fb)](_0x84919e(0x1ea)),_0x54e930=0x69+0x14;_0x1ed13f['scrollIntoView'](!![]);const _0xcaee30=window[_0x84919e(0x1d9)];_0xcaee30&&window[_0x84919e(0x1d1)](0x0,_0xcaee30-_0x54e930);const _0x16e02f=window[_0x84919e(0x209)](_0x84919e(0x211));_0x16e02f['matches']&&new bootstrap[(_0x84919e(0x1bb))](document[_0x84919e(0x1fb)](_0x84919e(0x214)));}),$(document)['on'](_0x1d15fb(0x1be),_0x1d15fb(0x224),function(_0x44d440){const _0x4d6a0a=_0x1d15fb;_0x44d440[_0x4d6a0a(0x202)]();let _0x57c6ce=$(_0x4d6a0a(0x1d4))['serialize']();jQuery('input[name=\x22strUsername\x22]')[_0x4d6a0a(0x1f5)]()!=''&&jQuery(_0x4d6a0a(0x1fe))[_0x4d6a0a(0x1f5)]()!=''&&jQuery('input[name=\x22ClassID\x22]')[_0x4d6a0a(0x1f5)]()!=''&&jQuery(_0x4d6a0a(0x222))['val']()!=''&&jQuery(_0x4d6a0a(0x1f0))[_0x4d6a0a(0x1f5)]()!=''&&jQuery(_0x4d6a0a(0x225))[_0x4d6a0a(0x1f5)]()!=''?$['ajax']({'url':_0x4d6a0a(0x227),'type':'POST','data':_0x57c6ce,'dataType':_0x4d6a0a(0x1f6),'success':function(_0x2e1771){const _0x1ea594=_0x4d6a0a;switch(_0x2e1771[_0x1ea594(0x1c2)]){case _0x1ea594(0x233):toastr[_0x1ea594(0x1d5)](_0x2e1771[_0x1ea594(0x23a)]);break;case _0x1ea594(0x216):document['getElementById'](_0x1ea594(0x20b))[_0x1ea594(0x229)](),setTimeout(function(){const _0xeb3bca=_0x1ea594;window[_0xeb3bca(0x23f)]=window[_0xeb3bca(0x23f)][_0xeb3bca(0x1f4)]+'/game';}),toastr[_0x1ea594(0x216)](_0x2e1771[_0x1ea594(0x23a)]);break;}},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){const _0x24c76b=_0x4d6a0a;toastr[_0x24c76b(0x1d5)](_0x24c76b(0x205));}}):toastr[_0x4d6a0a(0x1d5)]('Please\x20do\x20not\x20leave\x20BLANKS');;return![];}),$(document)['on']('click',_0x1d15fb(0x206),function(_0xed407e){const _0x469a37=_0x1d15fb;_0xed407e['preventDefault']();let _0x1177fa=$(_0x469a37(0x1e9))[_0x469a37(0x21f)]();return $[_0x469a37(0x22c)]({'url':_0x469a37(0x20c),'type':_0x469a37(0x1e4),'data':_0x1177fa+_0x469a37(0x20f),'dataType':_0x469a37(0x1f6),'success':function(_0x2981a4){const _0x3f8372=_0x469a37;switch(_0x2981a4[_0x3f8372(0x1cf)]){case _0x3f8372(0x216):document['getElementById']('formChangeUsername')[_0x3f8372(0x229)](),retrieveUserData(),toastr[_0x3f8372(0x216)](_0x2981a4[_0x3f8372(0x1cb)]);break;default:toastr[_0x3f8372(0x1d5)](_0x2981a4['Message']);break;}},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){const _0x4f9d59=_0x469a37;toastr[_0x4f9d59(0x1d5)]('System\x20got\x20broken!');}}),![];}),$(document)['on'](_0x1d15fb(0x1be),'#changepassword',function(_0x39f928){const _0x33e37a=_0x1d15fb;_0x39f928[_0x33e37a(0x202)]();let _0x594d94=$(_0x33e37a(0x1bc))['serialize']();return $[_0x33e37a(0x22c)]({'url':_0x33e37a(0x20c),'type':_0x33e37a(0x1e4),'data':_0x594d94+'&type=password','dataType':'JSON','success':function(_0x1fa7ba){const _0xda292c=_0x33e37a;switch(_0x1fa7ba[_0xda292c(0x1cf)]){case'success':document[_0xda292c(0x1fb)](_0xda292c(0x1e7))[_0xda292c(0x229)](),retrieveUserData(),toastr['success'](_0x1fa7ba[_0xda292c(0x1cb)]);break;default:toastr[_0xda292c(0x1d5)](_0x1fa7ba[_0xda292c(0x1cb)]);break;}},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){const _0x4ae639=_0x33e37a;toastr[_0x4ae639(0x1d5)](_0x4ae639(0x205));}}),![];}),$(document)['on'](_0x1d15fb(0x1be),_0x1d15fb(0x1ca),function(_0x3ea8bf){const _0x4627fd=_0x1d15fb;_0x3ea8bf['preventDefault']();let _0x4f6e9a=$(_0x4627fd(0x1dc))[_0x4627fd(0x21f)]();return $[_0x4627fd(0x22c)]({'url':_0x4627fd(0x20c),'type':'POST','data':_0x4f6e9a+'&type=email','dataType':_0x4627fd(0x1f6),'success':function(_0x32da52){const _0x3966d4=_0x4627fd;switch(_0x32da52[_0x3966d4(0x1cf)]){case _0x3966d4(0x216):document[_0x3966d4(0x1fb)](_0x3966d4(0x1d7))[_0x3966d4(0x229)](),retrieveUserData(),toastr[_0x3966d4(0x216)](_0x32da52[_0x3966d4(0x1cb)]);break;default:toastr['error'](_0x32da52[_0x3966d4(0x1cb)]);break;}},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){toastr['error']('System\x20got\x20broken!');}}),![];}),$(document)['on']('click',_0x1d15fb(0x1b9),function(_0x14c066){const _0x3b185b=_0x1d15fb;_0x14c066[_0x3b185b(0x202)]();let _0x11310b=$(_0x3b185b(0x23e))[_0x3b185b(0x21f)]();jQuery(_0x3b185b(0x231))['val']()!=''&&jQuery('input[name=\x22pwd\x22]')[_0x3b185b(0x1f5)]()!=''?$['ajax']({'url':'/api/login/now','type':_0x3b185b(0x1e4),'data':_0x11310b+'&web=true','dataType':_0x3b185b(0x1f6),'success':function(_0x33e042){const _0x6969e0=_0x3b185b;if(_0x33e042['bSuccess']==0x0)toastr[_0x6969e0(0x1d5)](_0x33e042[_0x6969e0(0x1ce)]);if(_0x33e042[_0x6969e0(0x21d)]['bSuccess']==0x1)setTimeout(function(){const _0x39a334=_0x6969e0;window['location']=NavigateTo==''?''+window[_0x39a334(0x23f)]['href']:window[_0x39a334(0x23f)][_0x39a334(0x1f4)]+'/'+NavigateTo;});toastr[_0x6969e0(0x216)](_0x6969e0(0x20d));},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){const _0x203834=_0x3b185b;toastr['error'](_0x203834(0x205));}}):toastr[_0x3b185b(0x1d5)]('Please\x20do\x20not\x20leave\x20BLANKS');;return![];}),$(document)['on'](_0x1d15fb(0x1be),_0x1d15fb(0x1e1),function(_0x28388e){const _0x3da261=_0x1d15fb;_0x28388e[_0x3da261(0x202)](),$['ajax']({'url':_0x3da261(0x1ec),'type':_0x3da261(0x1e4),'success':function(_0x30aa15){const _0x2cbdfe=_0x3da261;window['location']=window[_0x2cbdfe(0x23f)][_0x2cbdfe(0x1f4)];},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){const _0x2417eb=_0x3da261;toastr[_0x2417eb(0x1d5)](_0x2417eb(0x205));}});}),$(_0x1d15fb(0x230))[_0x1d15fb(0x1be)](function(){const _0x53ab6f=_0x1d15fb;let _0x3fb977=$(this)[_0x53ab6f(0x200)]('id');$[_0x53ab6f(0x22c)]({'url':_0x53ab6f(0x1c8),'type':_0x53ab6f(0x21c),'data':{'id':_0x3fb977},'dataType':_0x53ab6f(0x226),'success':function(_0x1176ea){const _0x2b3b5f=_0x53ab6f;let _0x3a32c1='';_0x3a32c1+=_0x1176ea['reward'][_0x2b3b5f(0x244)]!=0x0||_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1cc)]!=0x0||_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1e5)]!=0x0?'<h6>Currency</h6><table>':'';for(const [_0x11cb75,_0x134766]of Object[_0x2b3b5f(0x1c6)](_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)])){if(_0x11cb75==_0x2b3b5f(0x1d2)||_0x11cb75==_0x2b3b5f(0x234))continue;_0x3a32c1+=_0x134766!=0x0?_0x2b3b5f(0x213)+_0x11cb75+_0x2b3b5f(0x1c0)+_0x134766+'</font><br/></td></tr>':'';}_0x3a32c1+=_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x244)]!=0x0||_0x1176ea['reward'][_0x2b3b5f(0x1cc)]!=0x0||_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)]['Upgrade']!=0x0?'<table>':'',_0x3a32c1+=_0x2b3b5f(0x1c9),_0x3a32c1+=_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1d2)]?_0x2b3b5f(0x1ed)+_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1d2)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1d0)]+_0x2b3b5f(0x20a):'',_0x3a32c1+=_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)]['Item']?_0x2b3b5f(0x219):'';if(_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x234)])_0x3a32c1+=_0x2b3b5f(0x235)+_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x234)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1c7)]+_0x2b3b5f(0x221)+window[_0x2b3b5f(0x23f)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1f4)]+_0x2b3b5f(0x20e)+_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)]['Item']['id']+_0x2b3b5f(0x241)+_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x22d)][_0x2b3b5f(0x234)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1d0)]+_0x2b3b5f(0x1cd);$('#modal-title')[_0x2b3b5f(0x1ff)](_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x1d8)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1d0)]+'\x20<font\x20color=\x22green\x22>(&#36;'+_0x1176ea[_0x2b3b5f(0x1d8)][_0x2b3b5f(0x1ef)]+_0x2b3b5f(0x203)),$('#modal-body')[_0x2b3b5f(0x1ff)](_0x3a32c1),$('#modal-footer')[_0x2b3b5f(0x1ff)](_0x1176ea['footer']),$('#storeModal')['modal'](_0x2b3b5f(0x1e6));},'beforeSend':function(){renderLoading();},'error':function(){const _0x230a88=_0x53ab6f;toastr[_0x230a88(0x1d5)](_0x230a88(0x1fd));}});}),$(document)['on'](_0x1d15fb(0x1be),_0x1d15fb(0x21a),function(_0x330537){const _0x138f3b=_0x1d15fb;_0x330537[_0x138f3b(0x202)]();let _0x1f4d90=$('#CharpageId')[_0x138f3b(0x1f5)]();if(!_0x1f4d90)return toastr[_0x138f3b(0x1d5)](_0x138f3b(0x228));window[_0x138f3b(0x23f)][_0x138f3b(0x238)]=window[_0x138f3b(0x23f)]['origin']+_0x138f3b(0x1ee)+_0x1f4d90;});});
```

If someone really know how this can be decompiled, I tried with everything but still can't get normal output of it ;/

Comment: This is not "encryption" its obfuscation. And no, this is very hard to get back to shape. Try any JS deobfuscators, but even those cant recreate the function names but only get some structure back

Comment: [JSNice](http://jsnice.org/) is really good but it can do only so much. Looks like this code is just a jQuery plugin... as usual.